# QT phonon playback is failing when a QFILE is used for mediaSource, works fine when a string is passed

Tags: c++, qt, phonon

Below is the code I am using to play a video

```
 QFile* file =new QFile(“C:\\Video\\test.avi”);
   media->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(file));
   media->play();
```

Using this code the playback fails -what I see is the play bar at the bottom but the video never starts.

If I change the code to the following everything works as expected

```
  media->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(“C:\\Video\\test.avi”));
  media->play();
```

Are there additional initialization steps required when using an iodevice? Ultimately my code will be using a custom iodevice which is not working as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old post, but I wanted to clear up any confusion out in case it will help someone in the future.

1. QT does allow you to pass Phonon::MediaSource() a QIODevice. We successfully deployed our solution by creating our own subclass of QIODevice.

The reason it was not working for me was QT was having an issue with the codec I was using. When you use the QIO device you don't get the same format support as you would if you pass a string.

One other thing to note, while this solution works great on windows. On a mac when using the QIO device the entire file will be loaded into memory before it plays. In my case this was a deal breaker. Having an encrypted file is usless if the first thing you do is de-crypt the entire file and load it into memory.

Answer (score -1):

From the `Phonon::MediaSource` documentation:

> Warning: On Windows, we only support QIODevices containing the avi,
>   mp3, or mpg formats. Use the constructor that takes a file name to
>   open files (the Qt backend does not use a QFile internally).

I think that the last line should answer your question. Instead of a `QFile`, you can use a `QString`, or call the function `QFile::fileName` like this:

```
QFile* file =new QFile(“C:\\Video\\test.avi”);
media->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(file->fileName()));
media->play();
```

Comment: I guess the question is what is the QString used for? If I use QFile-FileName is Media source using the QFile object or is it creating a buffer on its own? 

What is required for the media source to use a custom IODevice on windows

Comment: My sample uses AVI, however I will be using an encrypted file that will require that I subclass IODevice. So, under windows the document states I need to use filename. If my class returns the filename , will mediasource use my buffer for reading? How does it use the fileName? 

With my current custom class when attempting to play it does read from the buffer but fails after the first few reads.

Comment: @user1127081 I can't tell you the details, because all I know is what is written in the doc, and it says that under Windows, the backend doesn't use a QFile, so probably it will retrieve a platform specific handle to the file and open it in other ways. So your solution of using a custom encrypted file might as well not work, also because the documentation clearly says that the file must contain a specific format. An idea would be to open the file, decrypting it in something like an internal buffer and pass that to the Phonon backend (although it might be expensive for very large files).

Answer (score -1):

If you take a careful look in the [Phonon Module docu][1], you will see that `MediaSource` cannot be constructed with `QFile*`.

By the way I don't see in your code any phonon paths. At least you should create audio sink and connect it with the mediaobject:

```
Phonon::AudioOutput *audioOut = new PhononAudioOutpu(Phonon::MusicCategory);//or the      category you need
Phonon::createPath(mediaObject, audioOutput);
mediaObject->play();
```

Works fine with QFile

Comment: the document states -On Windows, we only support QIODevices containing the avi, mp3, or mpg formats. Which tells me it does support QIODevices (Which QFILE is a subclass of) The document also states I should use QIODevice for types not supported. What am I missing